# Need to find duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, duplication

I received a database with a few million records in it, but apperently there might be duplicate records in them.

A user enters data into the database and a primary key is generated, however if the user enters the same data again, a new primary key will be generated for that data, even though the data has already been entered before. There are no checks on this.

I need to go looking for these duplicates, but I do not really know where to start. I first thought concatenating all cells except the primary key in a subquery and then count these rows and see which ones have a count higher than 1.

cfr.

```
pkey    recipe     fkey    comment
1   toast       3       tasty
2   curry       2       spicy
3   curry       2       spicy
4   bread       1           crumbly
5   orios       2       cookies
```

Here the curry entries are identical and I'd have to delete 1 of those.

However I read concatenating is unpredictable in mysql and it just feels a bit wrong to me as well.

Any hints ?

Comment: There are about 12 million questions and answers on [so] about finding dupes in SQL.  Have you checked there?

Comment: I think we need to keep this here so we can close future dupes without sending them to SO.

Comment: What's the best way to handle it since there are dupes on SO?  Make an answer with SO links?

Comment: Ow I didn't check stack, I assumed it would be on here. Sorry, still it might be interesting to have here, so if you copy an answer of stack that sovles it I'll accept it.

Comment: I deleted my answer - I can't come up with the query that will update your child tables foreign keys based on the duplicate-removed recipe tables new primary ids. You could set the constraints to cascade, but you will loose comments for duplicates that are removed in the recipe table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your table is called `ingredients`. Try the following:

Step 01) Create an empty delete keys table called `ingredients_delete_keys`

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients_delete_keys
SELECT fk,recipe,pkey FROM ingredients WHERE 1=2;
```

Step 02) Create PRIMARY KEY on `ingredients_delete_keys`

```
ALTER TABLE ingredients_delete_keys ADD PRIMARY KEY (fk,recipe,pkey);
```

Step 03) Index the `ingredients` table with fk,recipe,pkey

```
ALTER TABLE ingredients ADD INDEX fk_recipe_pkey_ndx (fk,recipe,pkey);
```

Step 04) Populate the `ingredients_delete_keys` table

```
INSERT INTO ingredients_delete_keys
SELECT fk,recipe,MIN(pkey)
FROM ingredients GROUP BY fk,recipe;
```

Step 05) Perform a DELETE JOIN on ingredients table using keys that don't match

```
DELETE B.*
FROM ingredients_delete_keys A
LEFT JOIN ingredients B
USING (fk,recipe,pkey)
WHERE B.pkey IS NULL;
```

Step 06) Drop the delete keys

```
DROP TABLE ingredients_delete_keys;
```

Step 07) Get rid of the `fk_recipe_pkey_ndx` index

```
ALTER TABLE ingredients DROP INDEX fk_recipe_pkey_ndx;
```

OK Here are all the lines in one block...

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients_delete_keys
SELECT fk,recipe,pkey FROM ingredients WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE ingredients_delete_keys ADD PRIMARY KEY (fk,recipe,pkey);
ALTER TABLE ingredients ADD INDEX fk_recipe_pkey_ndx (fk,recipe,pkey);
INSERT INTO ingredients_delete_keys
SELECT fk,recipe,MIN(pkey)
FROM ingredients GROUP BY fk,recipe;
DELETE B.*
FROM ingredients_delete_keys A
LEFT JOIN ingredients B
USING (fk,recipe,pkey)
WHERE B.pkey IS NULL;
DROP TABLE ingredients_delete_keys;
ALTER TABLE ingredients DROP INDEX fk_recipe_pkey_ndx;
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT

Notice that using MIN function helps keep the first pkey entered for fk. If you switch it to MAX function instead, the last pkey entered for fk is kept.